# Effects of Audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Im wondering wether or not if audits have any effects if you don't fail any. Is the only effects they have that you can get banned if you fail too many?

Comment: If you pass many audits consecutively, you will be presented with less audits.

Comment: They also give you a warm fuzzy feeling knowing that you passed the test!

Comment: @dan1111 considering How absolutely obvious most audits are I usually lack that :(